# Google Chrome can't access localhost domains

Tags: google-chrome

This is my first time trying Chrome and I can't access localhost, 127.0.0.1 or any other local domain I have setup from within Chrome 29.0.1547.66. They all work fine in Firefox and Internet Explorer, and have for years.

Nothing happens at all in Chrome when I try to load one of these pages. Loading icon just spins indefinitely.

What's up with Chrome?

```
System: Windows 8
Server: Softaculous AMPPS 2.0
```

---

*Additional troubleshooting performed with @50-3 in comments; comments have since been removed to free up space*

- Disabled same origin policy `--disable-web-security`
- Tried accessing via `127.0.0.1:80`, `http://localhost:80`
- Server not yet configured to allow connection from network IP address

Comment: The answer on this SO Q&A https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30467573/chrome-localhost-does-not-work is what worked for me. You need to clear out Chrome's DNS cache through this internal Chrome URL - chrome://net-internals/#dns.

Comment: None of the solutions mentioned on this page worked for me.

Comment: i had to return to default docker engine settings i.e "buildkit": true. and then localhost was back on chrome

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I finally found a [solution](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=224215#c2) to this. Go to chrome://flags and set "Built-in Asynchronous DNS" to "Disabled", then restart the browser.

This allows all local domains to be accessed. Looks like DNS was just choking up the issue.

Comment: This no longer works as of now because the mentioned flag is no longer available.

Comment: @BullyWiiPlaza check chrome://net-internals/#dns because it seems 'Internal DNS client enabled' is set to false by default.

Comment: @Alfabravo
Yes, it is set to `false`

Comment: My Google Chrome V52 64-bit for Mac had similar problem but chrome://flags had no settings related to DNS. Being desperate I "Reset all settings to default". And then it worked :)

Comment: I did `reset all to default`. And now it works. +1

Comment: This also works for the Chromium-based Edge.

Comment: I think it has been renamed to chrome://flags/#enable-async-dns

Answer (score 7):

**[Plagiarizing from Louie Bertoncin's answer on *Chrome: how to stop redirect from http:// to https://*](https://superuser.com/a/1251483/385380)--**

> My problem came from having a **.dev domain**, which was apparently recently registered as a [generic top-level-domain] and put in a commit to Chrome Canary. I found this out from a recent post I came across as I searched for my problem.
>
> If you have the same problem I do, **it appears that the best solution is to change your domain to be something other than .dev**. The article suggested .test with a potential solution of .localhost later down the road (via this proposal).

Comment: Yes ! Work for me changing .dev to .local

Comment: Changing .dev to .test also works for me. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 4):

The solution is this one. Go to chrome Settings -> Advances settings -> Privacy

And uncheck all options except this: "Protect you and your device from dangerous sites"

Will work !

Comment: Doesn't work. Tried this on OSX w/ Chrome 65.0.3325.181.

Comment: I had the same problem and this was the solution. It's really annoying that something so simple (i.e. chrome blocking whatever you are trying to do) does not come with a warning from the browser itself. Massive bug. Google, please fix.

Comment: Didn't solve my problem despite me thinking I had found the solution

Answer (score 2):

@sparrow had the right answer for me, but it was buried in the comments.  I am hoping this helps someone else.  @EcomEvo mentioned going to chrome://flags and looking for the "Built-in Asynchronous DNS".  Since his answer is old, that is no longer an option in Chrome.  However, I just did what @sparrow did.  Under "chrome://flags", I just chose "Reset all settings to default" and it started working again.

Comment: Failing in 2022.  This means I can no longer use Chrome for web development work!  Thank goodness for the Brave browser.  Frustrating though.

Comment: Don't solve in my case.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me: suffix the port number

> Problem with this URL: http://app.localhost/

Just add the Port number:

> Problem solved: http://app.localhost:8000/

Port number will vary based on what you use, XAMPP, APACHE, NGINX, Homestead.

I use Homestead.

Comment: It woesn't work for me: default HTTP port 80 is automatically removed

Comment: This doesn't work for me either, I'm using `http://app.localhost:3001/practice/jobs/2045` and it still fails with `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

Comment: @admac, Please confirm your port number based on the software you are using.