# Google chrome ignorning localhost for SOCKS5 proxy

Tags: google-chrome, proxy, localhost, socks-proxy

I am utilizing Google Chrome as a port forward via SOCKS proxy.

Essentially I am running the following command via terminal:
`ssh foo@bar.com -D 9999`

Then in Google Chrome, I set the SOCKS proxy to `127.0.0.1:9999`.

Problem is, I need to then access the host of `https://localhost/foo/bar` to be able to access what I need to access. This works fine on Firefox (when I modify the proxy settings), but not on Chrome.

If I go into `/etc/hosts` on my system and create an entry like this:

```
127.0.0.1 foobar
```

I can then go to `https://foobar/foo/bar` and everything works fine. It seems that chrome refuses to forward `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`. Is there any way around this?

Comment: [A similar question is here](https://superuser.com/questions/1418848/how-to-avoid-google-chrome-proxy-bypass-for-localhost), with similar suggested workarounds.

Answer (score 5):

By default, Chrome 72+ will NOT send `localhost` requests through your configured proxy.

You need to configure Chrome's proxy bypass list to contain `<-loopback>`, which is a special option that tells it to send `localhost` through the proxy.

Via command line, this looks like:

```
google-chrome --proxy-server=socks://127.0.0.1:9999 --proxy-bypass-list='<-loopback>'
```

Comment: Some more info: The [source code](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/refs/heads/master/net/proxy_resolution/proxy_bypass_rules.cc#16) has a special case for the exact text string `<-loopback>`. According to a comment in the source code, the meaning is:  _Remove the implicitly added bypass rules_

Comment: I don't know why, up until today on Ubuntu 22.04, I didn't need the `--proxy-bypass-list` flag when using a proxy server for the last few months, but now I do. This may be due to a recent update, as I see that openssh-client has had some very recent updates. FYI, the command line won't auto-complete the `--proxy-bypass-list` flag, but manually entering it as described in the answer worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar problem.(but I used SwitchyOmega, didn't know chrome already can use socks in build-in settings). At least, heading for my question could be the same.

Sometimes I use proxy ssh tunnel to access ports which are only acessible from server itself.

But Chrome started to ignore proxy settings for localhost so I had to search for workarounds too.

Currentl solution is to use wildcard dns services.
Example links to localhost: http://127.0.0.1.nip.io, http://127.0.0.1.xip.io

Comment: Can you explain in some detail what the user needs to do?  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.