# Stop Chrome forcing https on .dev domain

Tags: google-chrome, https, chromium

After updating to version 63 I have lost many hours figuring out what happened.

I really don't care if it is a valid TLD and I don't want to use .test.

So what are the ways around it? They did not include any settings for this.

Comment: https://superuser.com/q/565409/259665 ?

Comment: Specifically, this answer:  https://superuser.com/a/1251483/820  And this [blog post](https://security.googleblog.com/2017/09/broadening-hsts-to-secure-more-of-web.html) for rationale.  Basically, there's not much you can do.  You're using a TLD that is owned by Google and they have submitted it to the HSTS preload list.  You should start using`.test` or `.localhost` (still not official, but likely to become in the future)

Comment: Is there way to ignore preload list?