# How to stop redirect from http:// to https://

Tags: firefox, https, redirection

My library's OPAC (online public access catalog) website doesn't currently use HTTPS. Trying to view it with a secure connection 'crashes' it regardless of browser. However once I accidentally tried to visit the site via HTTPS and now it automatically tries to serve me the secure version no matter what I do.

I've had the same problem in Chrome for a while, and while I can use the solution presented [in this similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/565409/chrome-how-to-stop-redirect-from-http-to-https) and it will fix it for a little while by my next session the HTTP to HTTPS redirect is back in chrome.

For that reason I've been using Firefox mostly until today when I accidentally pasted an HTTPS link to the website into Firefox now Firefox will only serve the HTTPS version as well.

Comment: Maybe this might help a bit, about:config -  browser.urlbar.autoFill (false) ?

Comment: @Tech-IO Nope...

Comment: Or maybe using an add-on e.g. https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/noredirect/   But you may find an add-on by your self, just search for no redirect or no redirection.

Comment: have you tried to clear everything (ctrl-shift-del)?

Comment: The redirect is returned by the server.  You can't control that from the client.

Comment: @Adrien Nope. As I mentioned I have been able to visit the HTTP version for a while in FF, but can't access in Chrome for some time. For the moment I can use IE or Opera but I'm running out of browsers.

Comment: Maybe it's not a redirect then, as the status code 301 and 302 come from the server and cause the client to re-request the URI specified in the Location header of the 301/302 response.  It could be an HSTS thing where the site indicates a preference for https that FF is remembering?

Answer (score 12):

Exit Firefox and edit the file

```
/Users/Chloe/AppData/Roaming/Mozilla/Firefox/Profiles/xxxxx.default-999999/SiteSecurityServiceState.txt
```

Delete the line with your domain in it. Then restart Firefox. That will stop the redirection. That file is like Chrome's `chrome://net-internals/#hsts`.

The `xxx` and `999` will be random letters and numbers. The path is for Windows. Use `Menu > Help > Troubleshooting Information > Profile Folder` to find where your profile is located. In Linux the file is

```
/home/<USER>/.mozilla/firefox/profile.default/SiteSecurityServiceState.txt
```

Comment: Wow, very useful. Curious, how you were able to figure out that this is where such is stored?

Comment: @Coldblackice I probably knew where Firefox settings were and used `find AppData/Roaming/Mozilla/Firefox/Profiles -type f | xargs grep domain.com` in CygWin bash shell.