# How to stop redirect from http: to https: on router access

Tags: router, https, redirection

I have a big honkin' FIOS router from Verizon, and it has a problem. The router's webserver (e.g. http://192.168.1.1) must be accessed through http:. No https: at all - unlike my old router, where the browser would complain but I could still log in under it, this router won't accept the login under https: at all. So I HAVE to use http.

Now, all my browsers have plug-ins to ensure I use https whenever possible; e.g. "Https Everywhere". But even when I turn off the plugin to allow http access, it still redirects to https:.

Any idea why it is doing this? I suspect some setting somewhere in all of my browsers is cached to force redirects (I was finally able to log in from my phone, probably because I've never accessed the gateway there). I tried clearing browser settings, cookies, accessing incognito, etc., yet I still always get the redirect.

Any idea how I can fix this? It isn't as if I need to administer my router everyday, but I do need to have the ability to do it, and when I do, I don't want to spend a half hour finding the one browser on my devices that won't redirect to https: for that address.

Comment: possibly related: https://superuser.com/questions/1291062/how-to-stop-redirect-from-http-to-https. That seems to imply such redirects are due to settings in browsers that can't be removed by simply blowing away cached data.

Answer (score -2):

In Firefox open `about:config`, search for `network.stricttransportsecurity.preloadlist` and set it to false.

Comment: What does this setting do? What are the implications? How does it affect other websites?