# I can't visit websites that have “.dev” domain

Tags: dns, hosts-file, web-development

I'm trying to visit websites like https://get.dev, but instead of loading website, there appears "Resolving host" message and then I'm getting "This site can’t be reached get.dev’s server IP address could not be found.
DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN".

Here's what so far I have done:

1. I've tried visit websites from different browsers (Chrome, Safari, Firefox) - but with no luck. So it's not duplicate to [How to stop an automatic redirect from “http://” to “https://” in Chrome](https://superuser.com/questions/565409/how-to-stop-an-automatic-redirect-from-http-to-https-in-chrome)
2. My hosts configuration is pretty default:

```
 127.0.0.1       localhost
 255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
 ::1 localhost
 fe80::1%lo0     localhost
```

3. I had got installed Laravel Valet before, but I removed it and uninstalled dnsmasq (`brew uninstall dnsmasq`). Afer I removed I've restarted my computer.
4. I've tried also to ping those domains, but console (after some time) returns only `ping: cannot resolve get.dev: Unknown host`
5. It's possible to visit ".dev" websites from other computers in the same wi-fi network.

I'm wondering what else I can do to debug it and make it work?

Comment: Which DNS servers are you using on your computer? (If the OS is configured to use dnsmasq, which servers is dnsmasq using – _and_ is 'dev' mentioned anywhere in dnsmasq's config?)

Comment: do either of the following work? `dig get.dev` and `dig +trace get.dev` - if they fail, what's the output?

Comment: I'm using Cloudflare DNS (1.1.1.1). I've stopped and uninstalled dnsmasq using homebrew. I've checked also some old dnsmasq's config and searching "dev" returned 0 results.

For `dig get.dev` I'm getting:  https://pastebin.com/74NnEcFr
And for `dig +trace get.dev`: https://pastebin.com/G3WDGHZM

Comment: You really shouldn't be using using `.dev` on your local machine. These are [fully qualified TLDs](https://www.theregister.co.uk/2019/02/21/google_launches_dev/) now. You should swap to using `.localhost` as outlined in the [IETF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.localhost) documentation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to stop an automatic redirect from “http://” to “https://” in Chrome](https://superuser.com/questions/565409/how-to-stop-an-automatic-redirect-from-http-to-https-in-chrome)

Comment: _You really shouldn't be using using .dev on your local machine_

- Yeah, I know, I don't want to :) I just would like visit publicly available websites, that have ".dev" top level domain

Comment: @user2929594 the output from `dig` that you've shared implies the DNS lookup is successful... is this still an issue?

Answer (score 119, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out:

1. I used command `scutil --dns` which returned current resolvers configuration
2. There was entry:

```
 resolver #8
  domain   : dev
  nameserver[0] : 127.0.0.1
  flags    : Request A records, Request AAAA records
  reach    : 0x00030002 (Reachable,Local Address,Directly Reachable Address)
```

3. Then I went to the catalog `/etc/resolver` and I found there file called `dev`.
4. I've removed that file and everything started working just fine

Comment: Awesome thanks.  I found an old dev tool had created this entry `# Lovingly generated by Pow`

Comment: @kross Pow strikes again - same problem for me as well.  I learned about resolvers today as well.

Comment: It works. I just renamed dev to dev.bak in case I need to see its contents again.

Comment: You beauty! I've been pulling my hair out over this! Thanks!

Comment: You are my saviour mate I have been looking for this answer for many days when https://create-react-app.dev/ got blocked only on my mac. Thanks a lot

Comment: This has been plaguing me for years, long after I'd forgotten about having installed http://pow.cx/. Sure enough, there was some leftover config from Pow in that directory. THANK YOU.

Comment: This just saved my life. YES

Comment: Great tip. My issue was caused by `# Generated by puma-dev`

Answer (score 0):

That `dig` works implies that your DNS client config is correct, i.e. you're actually using the cloudflare service, and it's returning the correct results.

That `ping` doesn't work therefore implies that it's not actually querying DNS. Your `/etc/hosts` file is fine (and it'd be fast - you said that ping takes a while before it fails). Run `cat /etc/nsswitch.conf`; the line starting with `hosts:` configures where ping (and your browser, and all other general tools or applications) will try to get Name-to-IP data. If it doesn't read `files dns` (i.e. "use /etc/hosts, and then try DNS"), there's your problem.