# Http redirected to https when using fqdn name

Tags: ssl, nginx, https

I have configured my DNS service (bind9) on an Ubuntu server that has a public IP address. I have added in `/etc/bind/db.mydomain.com` (my domain zone) as an "A" record (with a public IP address) of a machine: `machine1.mydomain.com A  153.203.52.35`.

I can ping `machine1.mydomain.com` from the internet. I can also SSH to it without issue. The problem is that any attempt to reach the website hosted on this machine with a browser (http://machine1.mydomain.com) is automatically redirected to https (https://machine1.mydomain.com) and this gives the following error: "An error occurred during a connection to machine1.mydomain.com. SSL received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length. Error code: SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG".

Telnet to port 80 of the machine works fine:

```
$ telnet machine1.mydomain.com 80
Trying 153.203.52.35...
Connected to machine1.mydomain.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

My http server (nginx) configuration is configured with port 80 and no https redirection is configured. When I try to reach the website using the IP address of the server (http://153.203.52.35) the webpage displays with no issue and no redirection to https is done.

I am sure that the https redirection in my case has nothing to do with my nginx (see below my enabled site in nginx)

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;
        root   /var/www/mydomain.com;
        index index.php index.html index.htm ;
        server_name mydomain.com;
        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
                location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
       fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME  /var/www/mydomain.com$fastcgi_script_name;
}
}
```

I spent 2 days trying to figure out what is happening without success. Http redirection is usually done at http server level not in the DNS server. I am confused.

Any remark or advice that solve this issue will save me time and money.

Comment: What TLD is your domain under (if you don't want to reveal the whole thing)? What results do you get from `curl -k -L -i http://machine1.mydomain.com`?

Comment: hello,Thank you for your message. the TLD is ".life"
I am trying with apache now but still the same issue. The output of curl -k -L -i http://machine1.mydomain.com is:
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 01 May 2019 14:10:36 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.35 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.2m mod_ftp/1.0.1-dev
Last-Modified: Sat, 27 Apr 2019 05:15:31 GMT
ETag: "454-5877c23e22a2a"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 1108
Content-Type: text/html

<html>
 <head>
  <title>HTTP Server powered by Apache</title>
  <style>
   * {
    font-size: 12px;
    ......

Comment: I can see the following:
Request done with browser (firefox, chrome):

client (browser) ------TLSv1 Client Hello--->      http server 
http server   -----400 Bad Request------->  client (browser)


Request done with curl :

client (browser) ------ HTTP  GET / HTTP/1.1------>      http server 
http server   -----   HTTP HTTP/1.1 200 OK------->  client (browser)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the website could be shown with curl command, the only remaining thing was to clear the DNS and cache from the browser using the following post: [How to stop an automatic redirect from “http://” to “https://” in Chrome](https://superuser.com/questions/565409/how-to-stop-an-automatic-redirect-from-http-to-https-in-chrome).
The problem is solved.