# How to stop chrome automatically redirecting http to https?

Tags: google-chrome

Every time I go to http://192.168.1.1:80. Chrome tries to go to https://192.168.1.1:80
How do I force it to not do that? Note chrome://net-internals/#hsts does not seem to like IP addresses.

EDIT: P.S. It works in incognito mode. I need it to work without going to in cogneto, because my last pass browser addon doesn't have access to incognito mode. So I can't autofill the password to that site, if I use incognito. Also, even if I clear my cache, it's just going to happen again. I need a method to permanently force chrome to comply.

Further EDIT: Clearing the cache solved it; and now I have to reauth, and build that cache up over the course of weeks! THANKS GOOGLE. THANKS!!!

Comment: When I try that here with Chrome or with Edge, I just get a message that the internal device is not secure, go to Advanced and log in. Does that work for you?

Comment: I don't get that. I don't think I've ever gotten that.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/565409/how-to-stop-an-automatic-redirect-from-http-to-https-in-chrome?rq=1