# Stop Chrome from changing URL from HTTP to HTTPS when I edit it in the address bar

Tags: google-chrome, https

*Note:* this is not a duplicate of [How to stop an automatic redirect from “http://” to “https://” in Chrome](https://superuser.com/questions/565409/how-to-stop-an-automatic-redirect-from-http-to-https-in-chrome)

In Chrome 93 on Windows 7:

- I browse to http://example.net/a
- Chrome hides the protocol in the address bar, so I only see "example.net/a"
- I edit the URL to "example.net/b"
- This takes me to http**s**://example.net/b while I expected to go to http://example.net/b

Is there a way to disable this extremely annoying behaviour?

Note that there is no HSTS at play here - if I query for "example.net" under chrome://net-internals/#hsts it says "Not found". It happens even in Incognito mode without any extensions. Does not happen in Firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a bug in the Chrome implementation for hiding the protocol.

If one right-clicks the address-bar and selects
"Always show full URLs",
the bug does not arrive and `http` is maintained in the URL.

The most you can do is signal the bug. For workaround,
enable full URLs until (if) the bug is fixed.

Comment: OMG! I had no idea they finally added the option to show full URLs, which people (including myself) have been asking for. This works, thank you so much!