# Figure out what makes a 302 redirect for site on Chrome / Firefox (Apache-server)

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, apache-http-server, http, redirection

A site is running on a production environment, and needs to stay there, while I move and play with it on an online staging environment.

I moved all the files and pointed my host-file to the staging-server , like so: `123.123.123.12 example.org`. Where my staging-server has the IP: `123.123.123.12`.

When I visit `http://example.org` I get *immediately* redirected to `https://example.org`, which gives me all kinds of trouble, since that SSL-certificate is made using the production environment. So it tells me that my connection is unsafe.

I played around with this A LOT. Now I'm in a redirection-loop, where it bounces back and fourth between the `http://` and `https://`-version:

[image: find 302 redirect]

I assume a request 'moves' like this:

```
                            (step 1)   (step 2)  (step 3)
Visit http://example.org -> Browser -> Apache -> Browser -> Result (https://example.org)
```

So somewhere in either step 1, 2 or 3 - this redirect is made.

**Grand overarching question:** How do I figure out, where this 302-redirect comes from, so I can disable it - and access my site via `HTTP://` ?

---

### Attempt1 - Ensure the browser didn't do it

At first I tried:

- With developer tools open (network tab -> disable cache ticked).
- From incognito browser
- Clear all cached data and cookies and whatnot and restart browser.
- Try from different browser.

Both Chrome and Firefox really push `https`. So I Google how to disable 'forcing https'. I found [a brief version](https://superuser.com/a/881431/365568) and [a detailed version](https://howchoo.com/chrome/stop-chrome-from-automatically-redirecting-https). Non of them changed anything (I still get redirected).

### Attempt2 - Disable auto-redirect in VirtualMin

This happens here:

'System Settings' -> 'Virtualmin Configuration' -> 'SSL Settings' -> Untick: 'Redirect HTTP to HTTPS by default'

[Source](https://archive.virtualmin.com/node/45858).

The redirect-loop started after this, weirdly enough!

And I assume this 'just' adds some lines on the `.conf`-files for all domains on the server.

### Attempt3 - Ensure the `.htaccess`-file 'catches' traffic from port 80

I added these lines:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

... [Found here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19230960).

Same thing.

### Attempt4 - Add extra logs to Apache-setup

I figure I could maybe see some info about where the redirect came from. I tried adding some extra logging, by playing around with the `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/example.org.conf`, but that didn't lead anywhere. I tried following the suggestions from [this post](https://serverfault.com/a/10817), but that is outdated (see the upvoted-comment).

---

### Further info

- **Server technology:** [Webmin](https://www.webmin.com/) and [Virtualmin](https://www.virtualmin.com/). Running on a VPS I've setup myself. There are several other sites running and working on the server.

Comment: As far as I am aware, for HSTS, you may want to test with an old browser if you haven't already (at least earlier than Chrome ~91 or Firefox ~89). I believe there was a period there when the interface for removing HSTS sites was still available but actually did nothing.