# Why is Chrome ignoring /etc/hosts on OS X?

Tags: macos, networking, google-chrome, dns

I'm using OS X 10.8.5 and Chrome 30.

I added `127.0.0.1       youtube.com` to my `/etc/hosts` file such that it now contains this:

```
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
fe80::1%lo0     localhost

127.0.0.1       youtube.com
```

When I run the command `traceroute youtube.com` I receive the expected results (youtube.com is resolved to 127.0.0.1):

```
traceroute to youtube.com (127.0.0.1), 64 hops max, 52 byte packets
1  localhost (127.0.0.1)  0.272 ms  0.118 ms  0.063 ms
```

However, when I type youtube.com in Chrome, my browser doesn't establish a connection with 127.0.0.1 but instead with the "normal" IP address for YouTube. I would have expected Chrome to resolve youtube.com to 127.0.0.1.

I have Chrome configured to use my system's proxy settings. In OS X, when I go to System Preferences > Network > "Advanced..." > Proxies, I have selected "Auto Proxy Discovery".

Why is Chrome seemingly ignoring my `/etc/hosts` file?

Comment: Are you certain it's trying to resolve youtube.com and not www.youtube.com? It could also be that youtube.com has a 301 redirect which is cached by the browser so that it does not even attempt to contact youtube.com (not on my computer to check).

Comment: @user2313067 Thank you! I revised /etc/hosts to also have a line for www.youtube.com resolving to 127.0.0.1 and that did the trick.

Comment: @user2313067 You may want to post your comment as an answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is Chromium bypassing /etc/hosts and dnsmasq?](https://superuser.com/questions/723703/why-is-chromium-bypassing-etc-hosts-and-dnsmasq)

Comment: you are probably using a VPN or a chrome extension that ALTERS your connection in someway

Comment: Finally found the answer to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69532351/9519202

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try adding `www.youtube.com` to your hosts file. `youtube.com` is redirected permanently to `www.youtube.com`, so as long as you have visited `youtube.com` once, your browser caches this response and redirects you to `www.youtube.com`. This address isn't in your hosts file, so chrome logically resolves it correctly.

Comment: Do this to clear your redirects http://superuser.com/questions/304589/how-can-i-make-chrome-stop-caching-redirects or just use incognito mode for development

Comment: Adding `www` does not work for me. Even after clearing all my browser data and flushing my DNS. Perhaps this a anti-phishing measure baked into Chrome?

Comment: adding both naked and www. versions in the hosts file worked for me. I also disabled chrome://flags/#enable-new-preconnect in Chrome

Answer (score 14):

Google Chrome ignores your hosts file and does actual DNS lookups (despite what others may think, `/etc/hosts` is not part of DNS, it is what was used *prior* to DNS). While Google Chrome *should* be honoring those hosts file entries it does not. The hosts file, being an *alternative* to DNS, will be read when no DNS server is available (like if you disabled your network connection).

You can test this by adding "127.0.0.1 foobar.dev" to your hosts file, then enabling wireshark and watching on your network interface. Open up Chrome and put `http://foobar.dev/` in your address bar and go. You'll see a DNS query in Wireshark, something like:

```
2   1.668727000 192.168.32.104  8.8.8.8 DNS 75  Standard query 0x663a  A foobar.dev
```

FWIW, Google DNS returns 127.0.53.53 for foobar.dev.

```
3   1.706484000 8.8.8.8 192.168.32.104  DNS 91  Standard query response 0x663a  A 127.0.53.53
```

A workaround would be to use [HostAdmin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hostadmin/oklkidkfohahankieehkeenbillligdn) which is an older Chrome extension that makes Chrome use the hosts. However, newer versions of Chrome (>38, apprently) no longer support it.

Comment: Chrome is actually not ignoring `/etc/hosts` file on OS X. At least not Chrome v43 on OS X 10.10.3.

Comment: Wireshark tells a different story.

Comment: The fact that Chrome also queries the Google DNS might not mean /etc/hosts is ignored. This can be simply for optimization/logging/spying purposes. I use /etc/hosts file very often on OS X and have no problems with Chrome.

Comment: This is a known issue with Chrome and there is a ticket open with Chromium to fix it. Despite how you may *feel* about it, it is a thing and it needs to be fixed.
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=117655

Comment: When my host file has '127.0.0.1 foo.dev' and Chrome magically resolves foo.dev to 127.0.53.53, it is IGNORING my hosts file.

Comment: As I said. I have no problems with custom `/etc/hosts` entries. The bug report you linked suggests the problem is somewhere in `nsswitch.conf` instead but the default behaviour seems to use the `hosts` file anyway so your issue might not be related to this anyway.

Comment: I turned off my network (wifi) and Chrome/Firefox then went to the host file.

Comment: Yes, but with wifi on, Chrome *should* use the hosts file *first* before doing a DNS lookup. It does not. That is the problem.

Answer (score 9):

*I fixed this problem by:*
**Turn OFF "Protect you and your device from dangerous sites" in Chrome's Advanced Preferences.**

Chrome's built in "protection" includes checking a domain against their own DNS directly and bypassing certain types of host entries it deems "suspicious" or entries for sites that exist that are being overridden, which means most custom host entries are ignored.  Especially *.dev and *.local entries used for development.

Turning this off has resolved the issue 100% of the time for me.  This was driving me mad for months when doing local development and i couldn't find the answer listed anywhere, everyone just kept saying it couldn't be happening.  Turns out it was a simple toggle in advanced settings.  Hope this helps you as well, cheers.

Comment: Thanks, I knew it worked last week, I changed chrome options to default some days ago and it didn't work anymore. It worked!

Comment: Thanks, I knew it worked last week, I changed chrome options to default some days ago and it didn't work anymore. It worked!

It's called "Safe Browsing" in newer versions

Answer (score 2):

I stumbled upon this question by thinking that the `hosts` file didn't work on Chrome for macOS for the `.dev` fake domains I use for development.

**Actually it *does* work, at least on Chrome 77.**

The issue is not that the domain is not found, but that [all .dev are now automatically redirected to https](https://ma.ttias.be/chrome-force-dev-domains-https-via-preloaded-hsts/):

[image: This site can't be reached - Chrome]

If you double-click on the domain name, you can see the culprit:

[image: https]

Now that Google broke our `.dev`, as a solution, the link above suggests to move to another TLD for development, like `.test` or `.localhost`.

Comment: thanks man. I spend half of day trying to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

Localhost is a convention for 127.0.0.1 address that is an internal address for tcp/ip, however, Chrome is not using the /etc/hosts to solve the address, it is using a DNS server, therefore any address does not come from your /etc/hosts, but from a DNS server, if it were using the /etc/hosts, it will have to hold the entire www hostnames to solve any address.

Hope this helps.

Comment: -1. `/etc/hosts` overrides any DNS servers. Yes, if you are using _only_ `/etc/hosts`, it would have to contain all the domain names, but most setups also include DNS servers. If Chrome simply asks the OS to resolve the domain name, _like it should_, `/etc/hosts` will be checked first, and if it doesn't contain an entry, then a DNS query will be sent out.

Comment: `/etc/hosts` *should* override and DNS request but this is not the case with Google Chrome. It preforms its own DNS lookups despite what may in the hosts file. This is easily demonstrable. This is specifically an issue for local development using the `.dev` TLD.