# How to make Opera browser obey the etc/hosts file?

Tags: windows, dns, opera, hosts-file

Current version of Opera browser doesn't obey `etc/hosts` file for domains outside the local network. It looks to me like it is using its own DNS resolver.

For example if I create the following entries in hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1 stackoverflow.com  #IPv4 example
::1 www.stackoverflow.com    #IPv6 example
```

then Firefox, IE and network tools like **ping** evaluate *stackoverflow.com* as localhost (127.0.0.1) but Opera still visits real *stackoverflow.com* (even after restart).

I view this behavior as unsecure and annoying, as system-wide list of unwanted (dangerous or intentionally blocked) sites is ignored by the browser. Is there a way how to make Opera browser obey the content of `etc/hosts` file?

Comment: Do you have Turbo mode on? If you do - read somewhere how it works. That will explain everything.

Comment: @Kamil - you are right, it was caused by Turbo. (Initially I couldn't locate its visual indication and on/off switch.) Please add this as the answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is Turbo mode in Opera, I guess you have it turned on.

When it is turned on - browser may ignore your local DNS configuration.

> How does Opera Turbo work?
>
> The technology behind Opera Turbo is a **proxy server with server-side
>   compression of webpages**. A compression rate of up to 80% can be
>   achieved, in part by reducing the quality of images.

Source: [link](http://help.opera.com/Mac/11.60/en/turbo.html)

Comment: Thank you. Just a note that the sentence *"When it is turned on - browser is not using local DNS configuration."* is true only partially because for servers ***not found in Opera's own DNS***, entries in file `etc/hosts` remain in effect.

Comment: Oh, I didn't knew that! Thanks. Ill fix my answer.

Comment: Too bad that unlike in older Opera versions, **Turbo has no visual indication**. Of course, there is `Opera Turbo` menu item in Opera main menu, but if the item is checked, it only means that Turbo is *requested where possible*. But if you visit *www.youtube.com* which is NOT covered by Opera Turbo, you have no chance to see that Turbo is not in use. **Then you might be wondering why for www.youtube.com Opera obeys `etc/hosts` and why for www.stackoverflow.com it doesn't...**

Comment: I don't like how they changed Opera. It was one of a kind, very customisable, it was something diffrent, alternative and now... it become "just another browser". I thought they removed Turbo functionality totally, but it looks like it's still there :)

Answer (score 2):

I haven't got Turbo turned on but I still had this problem.  I found the following superuser post that solved my problem: [Why is Chromium bypassing /etc/hosts and dnsmasq?](https://superuser.com/questions/723703/why-is-chromium-bypassing-etc-hosts-and-dnsmasq).

Adapting the answer from that post I did the following:

1) In a new tab in Opera I entered the following URL:  **opera://net-internals/#dns**;

2) On the page I clicked the **Clear host cache** button.