# Chromium not checking hosts file

Tags: google-chrome

I was setting up a server, but Chromium decides to ignore my hosts file.

1. I unchecked "Predict network actions to improve page load performance"
2. I cleared chrome://net-internals/#dns
3. I restarted my virtual machine
4. I reinstalled Chromium and did 1-3 again
5. I reseted Chromium and did 1-3 again

I don't know what else to do, all the answers I found on Google does not work. Every other browser works but Chromium just decide to ignore hosts file.

Here is an image:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/G1kgC.jpg

Anyone has any idea on what went wrong?

Solutions in [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/723703/why-is-chromium-bypassing-etc-hosts-and-dnsmasq) do not work for me (That is 1 and 2, I tried 3 times). And I checked proxy settings, it's off.

Update: It seems that Chromium doesn't allow a domain to be pointed to localhost... Haven't found a workaround so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

::1 is accepted by pretty much everything but Chromium doesn't accept it. You have to use 127.0.0.1 to point to localhost.