# Chrome 60 ignoring /etc/hosts

Tags: google-chrome, dns, hosts-file, osx-el-capitan

Since approximetly the last update, Chrome does not respect the `/etc/hosts` file anymore. It does, but only for domains not listed in any public nameserver. It respects `devserver.local` but it does not for `stackoverflow.com` for example.

I have deactivated the automatic lookup services, deleted the browsers cache and did restart my notebook, I went do `chrome://net-internals/#dns` and cleared the hosts cache. None of it did help.

**What can I actually do to resolve official domains for development to my local address?**

[image]

OSX 10.11.6
Chrome 60.0.3112.90 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Q/As which did not solve the problem:

[Why is Chrome ignoring /etc/hosts on OS X?](https://superuser.com/questions/648133/why-is-chrome-ignoring-etc-hosts-on-os-x?rq=1)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37452361/why-is-my-hosts-file-entry-being-ignored-by-the-browser

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42636711/google-chrome-ignoring-hosts-file

Answer (score 2):

The solution was to disable "Auto Proxy Discovery".

I am using a transparent proxy so it does not need any configuration. My internet works even with no proxy configured (because it's a transparent proxy) but the option "Auto Proxy Discovery" has an impact on the DNS resolution.

I think this option was beeing enabled when a system wide update was triggered from a sysop.

[image]