# How to do a hard refresh without first loading a page?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, browser

We all know a "Hard Refresh" (eg <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> or <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>) will cause the browser to reload the current page (and other assets) from the server.

But what if that page contains a redirect (either from a `meta` tag or Javascript) that instantly redirects me to another page? How can I instruct the browser to load the page from the server?

I'm using Chrome and Firefox, but interested in solutions for any browsers.

Comment: I don't see the point of this question. If the page forwards, why do you need to do a hard refresh on the page? What could you be retrieving from the server ?

Comment: Because the latest version of the page may do something else: in my case the url wasn't publicly accessible so it redirected elsewhere, and when it became publicly accessible, the cached page would keep redirecting me away from it. Of course, the implementation could be improved, but to debug I wanted to be able to do a hard refresh.

Comment: Related: http://superuser.com/questions/304589/how-can-i-make-chrome-stop-caching-redirects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's also possible to clear cache from the source view:

Prepend the url in the address bar with `view-source:` (eg `view-source:http://myurl.com`), then perform a hard refresh.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this is the best way in Chrome:

> In the opened developer tools (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shft</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> or <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>) in the lower right corner click the little settings icon (it's like a gearwheel).
>
> Activate **Disable cache** check-box.

https://superuser.com/a/406331/126464

Comment: I had to do the same in Firefox. The accepted answer redirected me before showing the source.