# Chrome keeps redirecting to old port

Tags: google-chrome, apache-http-server, port, xampp

I was using XAMPP on port 100 for local development. I changed port back to 80 but Chrome won't let me use new urls.

Previously: localhost:100/mywebsite

Now when I open localhost/mywebsite it keeps redirecting me back to 100 port url which is not present. I have tried to clear browsing cache/history but it didn't work.

Comment: is this happen after the new chrome update?

Comment: i dont know, i think this has happened with all versions

Comment: if you've installed skype, it uses port 80 as default.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is posted here: [How can I make Chrome stop caching redirects?](https://superuser.com/questions/304589/how-can-i-make-chrome-stop-caching-redirects/869739)

I had the same issue while I was developing a new website locally by using Docker. I had to test some redirections on a previous project on a different port and then Chrome kept redirecting new project accessible by localhost to the previously used port. In the meantime, I was able to normally access localhost on the correct port by using Chrome in the incognito mode.

That did the magic:

> Chrome Menu Chrome Menu > Settings > Show advanced settings... >
>   Privacy > Click Clear browsing data...

I have cleared only cached images and files.