# Fake “.dev” domain added to hosts file for development purposes redirects to HTTPS in Chrome on Windows even when local dev server is not active

Tags: google-chrome, redirection, hosts-file

I am building an [Express.js](https://expressjs.com/) app locally. In order to test this in something other than localhost, I added the following entry to my hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1       mynewapp.dev
```

Without even starting the app, I accidentally tried `http://mynewapp.dev:3000` (this is where I intended the app to run), in Chrome. To my surprise Chrome redirected me to `https://mynewapp.dev:3000`.

Headers in the browser's console show:

> General:
>
> - Request URL: `http://mynewapp.dev:3000/`
> - Request Method: GET
> - Status Code: 307 Internal Redirect
> - Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
>
> Response Headers:
>
> - Location: `https://mynewapp.dev:3000/`
> - Non-Authoritative-Reason: HSTS
>
> Request Headers:
>
> - Provisional headers are shown
> - Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
> - User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like
> - Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36
> - X-DevTools-Emulate-Network-Conditions-Client-Id: 23A0CBD658A51DF4CA3B25A263078DA4

**How did this happen?** I have got no software redirecting the request, and my app isn't even running!

I am using:

- Chrome Version 68.0.3440.106 (Official Build) (64-bit)
- Windows 10 Enterprise

However this does not happen in:

- Microsoft Edge 40.15063.674.0 (Shows Error Code: INET_E_RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND)
- IE 11 (Shows Error Code: INET_E_RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND)

---

To answer the comments:

- `curl -I http://mynewapp.dev:3000` gets stuck and shows nothing.
- I also tried `chrome://net-internals/#events`, and found the request. This is what I saw:

  ```
  100382: URL_REQUEST
  http://mynewapp.dev:3000/
  Start Time: 2018-08-17 07:32:03.853

  t=16751 [st=   0] +REQUEST_ALIVE  [dt=1007]
                     --> priority = "HIGHEST"
                     --> url = "http://mynewapp.dev:3000/"
  t=16751 [st=   0]   +URL_REQUEST_DELEGATE  [dt=1]
  t=16751 [st=   0]      DELEGATE_INFO  [dt=1]
                         --> delegate_blocked_by = "extension AdBlock"
  t=16752 [st=   1]   -URL_REQUEST_DELEGATE
  t=16752 [st=   1]   +URL_REQUEST_START_JOB  [dt=6]
                       --> load_flags = 18432 (MAIN_FRAME_DEPRECATED | MAYBE_USER_GESTURE)
                       --> method = "GET"
                       --> url = "http://mynewapp.dev:3000/"
  t=16752 [st=   1]      URL_REQUEST_REDIRECT_JOB
                         --> reason = "HSTS"
  t=16752 [st=   1]      URL_REQUEST_FAKE_RESPONSE_HEADERS_CREATED
                         --> HTTP/1.1 307 Internal Redirect
                             Location: https://mynewapp.dev:3000/
                             Non-Authoritative-Reason: HSTS
  t=16752 [st=   1]     +URL_REQUEST_DELEGATE  [dt=6]
  t=16752 [st=   1]        DELEGATE_INFO  [dt=6]
                           --> delegate_blocked_by = "MojoAsyncResourceHandler"
  t=16758 [st=   7]     -URL_REQUEST_DELEGATE
  t=16758 [st=   7]      URL_REQUEST_REDIRECTED
                         --> location = "https://mynewapp.dev:3000/"
  t=16758 [st=   7]   -URL_REQUEST_START_JOB
  t=16758 [st=   7]   +URL_REQUEST_DELEGATE  [dt=0]
  t=16758 [st=   7]      DELEGATE_INFO  [dt=0]
                         --> delegate_blocked_by = "extension AdBlock"
  t=16758 [st=   7]   -URL_REQUEST_DELEGATE
  t=16758 [st=   7]   +URL_REQUEST_START_JOB  [dt=1000]
                       --> load_flags = 18432 (MAIN_FRAME_DEPRECATED | MAYBE_USER_GESTURE)
                       --> method = "GET"
                       --> url = "https://mynewapp.dev:3000/"
  t=16759 [st=   8]      URL_REQUEST_DELEGATE  [dt=0]
  t=16759 [st=   8]      HTTP_CACHE_GET_BACKEND  [dt=0]
  t=16759 [st=   8]      HTTP_CACHE_OPEN_ENTRY  [dt=0]
                         --> net_error = -2 (ERR_FAILED)
  t=16759 [st=   8]      HTTP_CACHE_CREATE_ENTRY  [dt=0]
  t=16759 [st=   8]      HTTP_CACHE_ADD_TO_ENTRY  [dt=0]
  t=16759 [st=   8]     +HTTP_STREAM_REQUEST  [dt=999]
  t=16759 [st=   8]        HTTP_STREAM_JOB_CONTROLLER_BOUND
                           --> source_dependency = 100392 (HTTP_STREAM_JOB_CONTROLLER)
  t=17758 [st=1007]        HTTP_STREAM_REQUEST_BOUND_TO_JOB
                           --> source_dependency = 100393 (HTTP_STREAM_JOB)
  t=17758 [st=1007]     -HTTP_STREAM_REQUEST
  t=17758 [st=1007]   -URL_REQUEST_START_JOB
                       --> net_error = -102 (ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED)
  t=17758 [st=1007]    URL_REQUEST_DELEGATE  [dt=0]
  t=17758 [st=1007] -REQUEST_ALIVE
                     --> net_error = -102 (ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED)
  ```
- Cleared the host cache from `chrome://net-internals/#dns`. Did not work.
- Stopped all Chrome extensions. No change in behavior.

Comment: Thanks for the response @Jake. I've updated the answer and actually took a look at `chrome://net-internals/#events`. But can't make head or tails of it. Will do some research. Thanks.

Comment: **Chrome preloads HSTS for `.dev`** Dupe https://superuser.com/a/1276430 and https://superuser.com/a/1251483 also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47768289 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47735877/ and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47707124/ and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47754347/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Beginning in 2018 Chrome and Firefox now forces HSTS for the `.dev` top level domain.

As [explained in this blog post](https://ma.ttias.be/chrome-force-dev-domains-https-via-preloaded-hsts/), while desktop developers have been using locally redirected (via `hosts`) `.dev` since almost forever, there apparently is now (as of May 2018) [a legitimate `.dev` generic top level domain (gTLD)](https://icannwiki.org/.dev) owned by Google. And there is [this Chromium commit from Jan 4, 2018 that explicitly states](https://chromium-review.googlesource.com/c/chromium/src/+/669923):

```
Preload HSTS for the .dev gTLD.
```

What fun! Additionally, [as of July 2018 Firefox does this as well](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1204153).

The simplest and most practical solution—for anyone who doesn’t want to set up HTTPS for local development—is to use another suffix such as `.localhost` or even `.local` or honestly anything in the world such as `*.foobar` and such.

But the long and short of this is in 2018, using `*.dev` suffix for local development will only cause more inadvertent headaches and confusion than anything else.